# Overriding chocolateyInstall.ps1 script with Ansible

Tags: sql-server, ansible, chocolatey

I would like to override the default powershell scripts that come with win_chocolatey module of Ansible. How do I do that?

In my case, I am trying to override the ChocolateyInstall.ps1 that comes with MsSqlServerManagementStudio2014Express. I would like to pass a few more parameters such as system administrator password and instance names during the silent installation of MsSQLServer.

I have tried giving these additional parameters with "install_args" and "params" options in win_chocolatey module call in my ansible playbook. But there are no handlers written in MsSqlServerManagementStudio2014Express's powershell scripts to include them during silent installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Package Parameters vs Install Arguments

Install Arguments (`--install-arguments` option for `choco.exe`) are completely invisible to the packaging, and they are appended to the current set of silent arguments in the package. One can also override them completely with `--override-arguments`. In the commercial editions of Chocolatey, you can also pass `--install-arguments-sensitive` to keep secrets out of logs.

Package Parameters (`--package-parameters`|`--params`) are different, can be used with anything related to packaging (not just for the installer), but must also be present in the packaging itself. For commercial editions and secrets, you also have `--package-parameters-sensitive`.

#### Option 1: Community Repository Packages

You would need to ensure that the package is using `Install-ChocolateyPackage`, `Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage`, or other built-in methods to know that install arguments can be used with the package. If you need parameters, you will need to work with the maintainers of the package to get those implemented.

#### Option 2: Use Your Own Packages

If you are using Chocolatey in an organization, you will want to use your own package you store somewhere internally. That guarantees much more reliability and repeatability, something that is instrumental to organizational use of anything.

Plus you can bake installers directly into the package as you are not subject to distribution rights internally, providing an even more reliable experience.

It is especially helpful to read over and understand this when planning for Chocolatey in an organization: https://chocolatey.org/docs/community-packages-disclaimer